# Node.js (TypeScript) Postgres client does not appear to run insert statement on Pool.query, and callback does not execute

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, node-postgres

Hopefully this is a minimum viable example ->

`routes.ts`

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { QueryResult, Pool } from "pg";

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DOCKER_USER,
  host: "localhost",
  database: process.env.DOCKER_DB,
  password: process.env.DOCKER_PASSWORD,
  port: 5432,
});

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/log/hub", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log("Made it here!");

  const username = "PLACEHOLDER";
  const json = { a: "b" };
  const now = new Date();
  const cachedId = "12345";

  pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO data_actions (username, json_payload, cache_id, action_timestamp) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
    [username, json, cachedId, now],
    (error: Error, results: QueryResult) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      res.status(201).send(results);
    }
  );
});

export = router;
```

```sh
echo $DOCKER_USER,$DOCKER_DB,$DOCKER_PASSWORD
```

produces
`docker, docker, docker`

I have verified in the client that these values match the values printed above and that they match the credentials set up in the Docker container for Postgres.  I'm able to connect to the database on port 5432 with pgAdmin4 and view the database I expect, which looks like this:

```
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  | Owner  
--------+------------------+-------+--------
 public | data_actions | table | docker
(1 row)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM data_actions;
```

produces

```
 username | json_payload | cache_id | action_timestamp 
----------+--------------+----------+------------------
(0 rows)
```

I am able to reach the express router endpoint at localhost:5000, so everything downstream is not the problem.  I think the issues lies somewhere with how I'm using `pg`.  Does anything obvious stand out here?  I have a feeling I'm missing something small and I'm banging my head against the keyboard trying to figure out what's going wrong.

**EDIT**:  The relation shows 1 row where select statement returns 0 rows.  This is because I deleted the row I inserted from pgAdmin before I posted here.  Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: Does it work within a `pool.connect` callback? Is the callback of `pool.on` being called?

Comment: @Michiel No to both questions, which I guess means the issue lies with the connection.  Doesn't make sense though.  I've triple checked the credentials, the port, and of course it's running on my machine.  Is there a way to diagnose authentication issues with the pg client?  I'd figure that would be in the connect callback but that's not executing at all either.

Comment: What version of nodejs and pg is installed? A week ago I had a similar problem after I updated from node 12 to 14, I had to update pg as well. Btw, a minimal viable example can be made without express.

Comment: Did updating pg or downgrading nodejs work?

Comment: @Michiel Thanks for following up, I should have reported back.  Updating pg fixed the issue.  If you want to post the comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the `pg` module. Old versions might not work with newer Nodejs versions.